# SharePoint 2013 App ideas

Tags: 2013

I have developed a SharePoint 2013 portal for my company. Currently we are using for document libraries for different divisions.

We have a Oracle EBusiness application which HR, Finance and Store are using. I want to learn SharePoint 2013 APP development so what kind of App I can develop ..any ideas? and how different is a Web application/Webparts Vs. App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Which kind of App to develop**

If the development in part of you job, then it should be the kind of App that your business needs.

If the development is done in your spare time, then it should be either as above or something which you think would be one (or more) of following:

- fun to develop
- possible to sell
- for greater good (maybe something like [Humanitarian Toolbox](http://www.htbox.org/))

**How is App development different**
Good starting point is the MSDN articles:

- [Apps for SharePoint compared with SharePoint solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [Deciding between apps for SharePoint and SharePoint solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268593%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Per thanks for your reply. Can Travel Desk, Complain Management can be considered as APP ? does it work like a normal SharePoint application from which I can call a webservice to pull/push data from Oracle EBS database and populate information on APPS form?

Comment: Both your examples could be made as Apps. Interacting with other systems may be hard if you're creating a SharePoint hosted app (pure JavaScript) due to security. But if you create a provider hosted app you have the full freedom/power of your environment which could be ASP.NET MVC (or WebForms) or whatever you want.